# Host discovery in AWS VPC

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I just have a basic question. What is the recommended way to handle automatic host discovery in an AWS VPC? I have these Servers running and I want to figure out a neat way to skip having to configure the /etc/hosts file on every machine to get them to talk to each other. I know I can enable DNS support for my VPC but that does not resolve host names that the software I am running generates.

I'm building an high availability cluster of RabbitMQ (w/ autocluster plugin) using autoscaling groups with launch configs, but they don't cluster unless I add all the peers to the hosts file, i.e. for host rabbit@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx I would have to add the resolution of "Private IP" and host name "ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this post for the many ways to do **[Host / Service discovery on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-technical-content/latest/microservices-on-aws/service-discovery.html)**. Many of the methods will be suitable for your usecase.

Also consider using managed **[Amazon MQ](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/)** instead of building and managing your own RabbitMQ cluster. It comes with the usual benefits of a managed service - you only use the service and don't have to care about all the low-level stuff like OS patching, clustering, fail overs, service discovery, etc. There is a nice tutorial **[Migrating from RabbitMQ to Amazon MQ](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-from-rabbitmq-to-amazon-mq/)**.

Hope that helps :)